# Recovering a specific job definition from an MSDB backup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We've been asked to recover a specific SQL 2005 job from how it existed at a certain time in the past. We have MSDB database backups from that time period, but I can't overwrite the current MSDB database, because I don't want to lose more recent changes to other jobs on that server.

If I restore it as a copy (call it MSDB_old or something), how can I extract the information for that one job? Or would I need to restore it over the MSDB database on a scratch server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to restore to a scratch server, you can restore it to something like you say (MSDB_old) and do a query to get your job back:

```
USE msdb_old
SELECT * FROM sysjobs
JOIN sysjobsteps ON sysjobs.job_id=sysjobsteps.job_id
WHERE sysjobs.NAME='My Lost Job'
ORDER BY sysjobsteps.step_id
```

You'll have to restore

- the entry in sysjobs
- each entry in sysjobsteps related to the above entry in sysjobs
- entries in sysjobhistory if you want history back
- entries in sysjobschedules to get your schedules back

**EDIT:** Here's a script that should do it in SQL 2005 and 2008 (assuming your job was called "My Lost Job" and you restored to MSDB_Old)

```
DECLARE @JobID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SELECT @JobID = job_id FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobs WHERE NAME='My Lost Job'

INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobs
SELECT * FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobs
WHERE job_id=@JobID

INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
SELECT * FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobsteps
WHERE job_id=@JobID

SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory ON
INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
    (instance_id,job_id,step_id,step_name,sql_message_id,sql_severity,
     [message],run_status,run_date,run_time,run_duration,operator_id_emailed,
     operator_id_netsent,operator_id_paged,retries_attempted,[server])
SELECT
    instance_id,job_id,step_id,step_name,sql_message_id,sql_severity,
    [message],run_status,run_date,run_time,run_duration,operator_id_emailed,
    operator_id_netsent,operator_id_paged,retries_attempted,[server]
FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobhistory
WHERE job_id=@JobID
SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory OFF

INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules
SELECT * FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobschedules
WHERE job_id=@JobID
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, it saved us from a corrupted msdb! The sysjobschedules part fails with a foreign key error, though, we add the recreate the schedules manually.

Comment: We also add to run 
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name = N'NightlyBackups'
to register them with the server.

Answer (score 3):

The script is loosely based on [this one](https://serverfault.com/a/34094) in the accepted answer. It has been updated for SQL 2014, with exception handling, atomic transactions, and a few other improvements.

```
-- Script for SQL 2014
DECLARE @JobID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
declare @servername sysname

set @servername = @@SERVERNAME

SELECT @JobID = job_id 
FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobs 
WHERE name='My Lost Job'

BEGIN TRAN

BEGIN TRY

INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobs
SELECT * FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobs
WHERE job_id=@JobID

INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
SELECT * FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobsteps
WHERE job_id=@JobID

SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory ON
INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
 (instance_id,job_id,step_id,step_name,sql_message_id,sql_severity,
 [message],run_status,run_date,run_time,run_duration,operator_id_emailed,
 operator_id_netsent,operator_id_paged,retries_attempted,[server])
SELECT
 instance_id,job_id,step_id,step_name,sql_message_id,sql_severity,
 [message],run_status,run_date,run_time,run_duration,operator_id_emailed,
 operator_id_netsent,operator_id_paged,retries_attempted,[server]
FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobhistory
WHERE job_id=@JobID
SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory OFF

-- New insert in sysschedules 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysschedules ON
INSERT msdb.dbo.sysschedules (schedule_id, schedule_uid,
         originating_server_id, name, owner_sid, enabled,
         freq_type,freq_interval, freq_subday_type,
         freq_subday_interval, freq_relative_interval,
         freq_recurrence_factor, active_start_date, 
         active_end_date, active_start_time, active_end_time,
         date_created, date_modified, version_number)
SELECT schedule_id, schedule_uid, originating_server_id, name,
       owner_sid, enabled, freq_type, freq_interval, freq_subday_type,
       freq_subday_interval, freq_relative_interval,
       freq_recurrence_factor, active_start_date, active_end_date,
       active_start_time, active_end_time, date_created, date_modified,
       version_number 
FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysschedules a
WHERE schedule_id = (select schedule_id from msdb_old.dbo.sysjobschedules b where job_id=@JobID )
SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysschedules OFF

INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules
SELECT * FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobschedules
WHERE job_id=@JobID

-- Alter job as local job
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id=@JobID, @server_name = @servername

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    ROLLBACK TRAN

    RETURN
END CATCH

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: @DeerHunter: If this is an improvement working on MSSQL2014 only, it should not be edited back into the answer, as this was concerned with a much older version.

Comment: Just to point out, if any jobs had categories set, those categories would have to be imported as well (or update category_id to 0 in table). Otherwise those jobs wouldn't be displayed in the job list in the object explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to extract a single job from MSDB is to right-click the job in SSMS and say Script Job - then take the script to the target server and run it to recreate the job (with potentially some modifications needed).

This only works if the msdb is restored as msdb - which means in your case you'd have to restore the backup as msdb on a scratch server.

I guess you could restore it as a copy of msdb and then manually pull everything out of the various msdb_copy.dbo.sysjobs/sysjobsteps/sysjobschedules/sysjobservers tables using a join.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Hi, I'd like to add upon squillman's answer. I tested it in 2008 R2.

First, by fixing the error with FK violation with sysjobschedules and sysschedules.

Secondly, by running dbo.sp_add_jobserver.

Lastly, by having it loop through all the jobs in msdb_old.dbo.sysjobs for a complete replication.

```sql
DECLARE @JobID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
declare @jobname nvarchar(128)

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT job_id 
FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobs

OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @JobID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
SELECT @jobname = name FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobs WHERE job_id=@jobid
print @jobname

print 'insert in sysjobs'
INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobs
SELECT * FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobs
WHERE job_id=@JobID

print 'insert in sysjobsteps'
INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
SELECT * FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobsteps
WHERE job_id=@JobID

print 'insert in sysjobhistory'
SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory ON
INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
    (instance_id,job_id,step_id,step_name,sql_message_id,sql_severity,
     [message],run_status,run_date,run_time,run_duration,operator_id_emailed,
     operator_id_netsent,operator_id_paged,retries_attempted,[server])
SELECT
    instance_id,job_id,step_id,step_name,sql_message_id,sql_severity,
    [message],run_status,run_date,run_time,run_duration,operator_id_emailed,
    operator_id_netsent,operator_id_paged,retries_attempted,[server]
FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobhistory
WHERE job_id=@JobID
SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory OFF

print 'insert in sysschedules'
SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysschedules ON
INSERT msdb.dbo.sysschedules
( [schedule_id]
,[schedule_uid]
,[originating_server_id]
,[name]
,[owner_sid]
,[enabled]
,[freq_type]
,[freq_interval]
,[freq_subday_type]
,[freq_subday_interval]
,[freq_relative_interval]
,[freq_recurrence_factor]
,[active_start_date]
,[active_end_date]
,[active_start_time]
,[active_end_time]
,[date_created]
,[date_modified]
,[version_number])
SELECT  s.[schedule_id]
,s.[schedule_uid]
,s.[originating_server_id]
,s.[name]
,s.[owner_sid]
,s.[enabled]
,s.[freq_type]
,s.[freq_interval]
,s.[freq_subday_type]
,s.[freq_subday_interval]
,s.[freq_relative_interval]
,s.[freq_recurrence_factor]
,s.[active_start_date]
,s.[active_end_date]
,s.[active_start_time]
,s.[active_end_time]
,s.[date_created]
,s.[date_modified]
,s.[version_number]
FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysschedules s, msdb_old.dbo.sysjobschedules j
WHERE j.job_id=@JobID and s.schedule_id = j.schedule_id
SET IDENTITY_INSERT msdb.dbo.sysschedules OFF

print 'insert in sysjobschedules'
INSERT msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules
SELECT * FROM msdb_old.dbo.sysjobschedules
WHERE job_id=@JobID

print'exec adds job in server'
use msdb
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobid

FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @JobID
END

CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
```

Answer (score 0):

just restore to any server with a new name, I have done this many times before...